# apache: how to map #foo to #bar

Tags: apache-httpd

Can apache2 redirect or rewrite /path/#foo to /path/#bar ?

I found that when using Redirect or RewriteRule, it always omit the URL part start from #, cause it impossible to replace such a url hash #foo to #bar.

Comment: Browsers aren't supposed to send the `#foo` to the server. They should manage the fragments themselves. So Apache shouldn't see it at all.

Comment: OMG, I haven't noticed that browser never send `#foo` to the server, thank you for your explanation.

Answer (score 0):

As @muru explained, Browsers aren't supposed to send the #foo to the server. They should manage the fragments themselves. So Apache shouldn't see it at all.

So this problem is totally not a problem.